# Please define: "Maximum Memory Supported - 10GB, Service Upgradable Only"

Tags: laptop, memory, upgrade

I am assuming this means that the RAM modules can only be inserted/removed from some place very inconvenient? Maybe under the keyboard?

Or does this mean something more strict, as in the only way to get an upgraded module in the laptop is via some special toolset, or verified through the hardware to allow the system to recognize the new memory? I ask because I'd want to know if I need to buy my own additional RAM, since I can't seem to find a way to get to 8GB. A Google search result turned up very little other than hits for shopping.

Here is the laptop in question: http://www.tigerdirect.com/applications/SearchTools/item-details.asp?EdpNo=4817549&sku=T78-144301

Comment: How can a Laptop  support 10 GB RAM? I've never heard of this. Currently it's normally a multiple of 8. Before it was 2 or 4.

Comment: I'd say that you need to access the memory by removing lots of things to get to it or that it will void the warranty if you don't have them do it. Personally I wouldn't by a Toshiba laptop, if you want a good laptop buy a [Lenovo](http://lenovo.com)

Comment: @sinni800 - Because it has onboard memory plus 1 memory modual it seems.  The current configuration is 6GB, this is not unusal, I remember my 3MB of memory very well.  This is not a laptop its a ultrabook the rules are different on the motherboard.  If you are really curious download the spec sheets from Toshiba.

Comment: @Ramhound I just saw that, 2gb are soldered on, 4gb are built in as a stick.